# Is it possible to create a ternary (triangular) graph template in ArcGIS 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, graph

Is is possible to edit a .tee graphing template file to create a ternary diagram (example can be found at http://csmres.jmu.edu/geollab/Fichter/SedRx/readternary.html)?

I'm aware of the clever method found at https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=661a8e7c463a4bd2b529f01221efa8f2. However, that creates a series of shapefiles in a separate data frame. If possible, I'd like to use the built-in graphing tools via ArcGIS.